# Exponential distribution lightbulb

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

The time it takes for a lightbulb to burn out is exponentially distributed with mean $u$ which is a random variable. Asssume that $u$ is distributed with density

$$f(x)=\frac{8}{x^3}$$

for $x \in [2, \infty)$.

What is $P(\text{lightbulb is burned out by time } 7)=P(E)$?

$$P(E)=1-P(E^c)=1-\int e^{-7x}\frac{8}{x^3}dx$$

Where does the $-7x$ come from?

Comment: Which aspects of the posted answer are causing you trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional lifetime random variable for a fixed mean $\mu$ is given by $$T \mid \mu \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\mu)$$ where $$f_{\mu}(x) = 8x^{-3}, \quad x \ge 2.$$  So in particular, recall that the CDF of an exponential distribution is $$\Pr[T \le t \mid \mu] = F_{T \mid \mu}(t) = 1 - e^{-t/\mu}, \quad t \ge 0.$$  Thus by the law of total probability $$\Pr[T \le 7] = \int_{x = 2}^\infty \Pr[T \le 7 \mid \mu = x] f_\mu(x) \, dx = \int_{x=2}^\infty (1 - e^{-7/x}) \cdot 8x^{-3} \, dx.$$  Note this is equivalent to what you wrote in your question, since we know that $$\int_{x=2}^\infty f_{\mu}(x) \, dx = 1.$$

Comment: I'm sorry..but I still don't really follow..

Comment: Can you be more specific about what aspects of my explanation you would like to have further clarified?